# Where is myProject.sqlite located in Lion OSX Xcode 4.1?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, core-data

I cannot locate my core data sqlite file in OS 10.7. Do any of you know how to locate it.

Thanks
Kasper

Comment: Are you building for MacOS or iOS?

Answer (score 2):

It is kept in the same place as previous ios versions, however... the Library folder is hidden with a Finder flag, you can undo this flag to make it visible again.

To do this, open the Terminal utility and run the following command:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

The folder and all sub directories will then be visible immediately.