# Where is a sqlite core data store kept in Lion?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is myProject.sqlite located in Lion OSX Xcode 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816366/where-is-myproject-sqlite-located-in-lion-osx-xcode-4-1)

I'm trying to delete my Core Data store for a test app I'm running as it contains entries and the model has changed. I can't seem to find it under Lion. I was expecting to look in /Library/Application Support/My App Name but there's no folder there for my app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's not ~/Library/Application Support/My App? Either way, the file should not have moved.

Comment: The simulator now has an option to "Reset Content and Settings..." under the iOS Simulator menu.

Comment: @sosborn nope. I did an 'ls' in terminal in the Application Support directory and it didn't show up with anything to do with my app

Comment: @Terry Wilcox sorry, should've been specific, this is a mac app not an iOS app. I'm not using the simulator at all :)

Comment: When you run your app it show the incompatible store error, right? If so,then what I would is NSLog the location that the application is loading the store from. I think the loading code is in the app delegate.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where was it?

Answer (score 3):

On Lion with XCode 4.1 I found this under ~/Library/appname/appname.storedata

After deleting that file I re-ran my Mac app and core data was like new.

Comment: It seems to have moved from ~/Library/Application Support/appname/ recently...

Answer (score 0):

What kind of application did you build? If you built a “shoe box” type Core Data application, then the file is wherever configured the persistent store coordinator to write it.

This is typically done in the application controller/delegate.

Answer (score 0):

It is kept in the same place as previous ios versions, however... the Library folder is hidden with a Finder flag, you can undo this flag to make it visible again.

To do this, open the Terminal utility and run the following command:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

The folder and all sub directories will then be visible immediately.